# Surround all lines in a text file with quotes ('something')

Tags: linux, unix, text, directory, grep

I've got a list of directories that contain spaces.

I need to surround them with ' ' to ensure that my batch scripts will work.

How can one surround each new line with a ' and a ' (quotes).

e.g.

File1:

```
/home/user/some type of file with spaces
/home/user/another type of file with spaces
```

To

File2:

```
'/home/user/some type of file with spaces'
'/home/user/another type of file with spaces'
```

Comment: Do you need to quote apostrophes in the string?

Comment: No just around the string. You know - so my script doesn't fail when it comes upon a path with a space.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use sed?

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"
```

Or, as commented below, if the directories might contain apostrophes (nightmare if they do) use this alternate

```
sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"
```

Comment: Command worked perfectly - obviously if anyone was to use this on a file the would append it at the end of the command.

Comment: what if the filename contains an apostrophe?

Comment: I would modify this to sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"

Comment: In my scenario, I wanted double quotes and comma delimited sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\"\1\",/"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but pet peeve... the "-e" is superfluous since only one script is present.

Answer (score 7):

Using sed:

```
sed -i "s/^.*$/'&'/g" filename
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me Adam - get various errors depending on the particular filename - maybe need -e in there?

Comment: Pretty sure I popped exactly that into cygwin, and it did fine.  Could have made a type though.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer awk (it's faster than bash and very easy to extend):

```
awk '{print "\'" $0 "\'"}'
```

Comment: was not working for me. But this worked: ```awk '{print "\"" $0 "\""}'```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sed(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to insert single quotes at the beginning and end of each line in a file as so:

```
sed -i~ -e "s/^/'/;s/$/'/" the_file
```

Answer (score 3):

very simple logic, you just need to echo the quotes in front and behind.

```
while read -r line
do
  echo "'$line'"
  # do something
done < "file"
```

Comment: Why were all the answerers and prior voters bent on using sed? The question didn't ask for it. Does this work? I'm not familiar with Bash control flow.

Comment: @AaronHall Because sed is a great program for transforming text and the question didn't specifically ask for bash

Answer (score 0):

Using [sd](https://github.com/chmln/sd), to surround with `'` the command looks like:

```
sd '(.*)' \''$1'\'
```

to surround with `"` the command looks like:

```
sd '(.*)' '"$1"'
```

Hopefully you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` and `printf`

```bash
< file xargs printf "'%s'\n" |
  sponge file # optionally sponge back to modify the file
```