# Bash: Why mv won't move files under this for-loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Using a Bash script, I'd like to move a list of files by using a for-loop, not a while-loop (for testing purpose). Can anyone explain to me why mv always acts as file rename rather than file move under this for loop? How can I fix it to move the list of files?

The following works:

```
for file in "/Volumes/HDD1/001.jpg" "/Volumes/HDD1/002.jpg"
do
    mv "$file" "/Volumes/HDD2/"
done
```

UPDATE#1:
However, suppose that I have a sample_pathname.txt

```
cat sample_pathname.txt
"/Volumes/HDD1/001.jpg" "/Volumes/HDD1/002.jpg"
```

Why the following for-loop will not work then?

```
array=$(cat sample_path2.txt)
for file in "${array[@]}"
do
    mv "$file" "/Volumes/HDD2/"
done
```

Thanks.

System: OS X
Bash version: 3.2.53(1)

Comment: The script looks correct to me. Why do you think it acts as a "file rename rather than file move"? Does it fail with an error?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -ld /Volumes/HDD2`?

Comment: I am getting output like this.</br>  

`mv: rename /Volumes/HDD1/001 to /Volumes/HDD2/001: No such file or directory`
`mv: rename /Volumes/HDD1/002 to /Volumes/HDD2/002: No such file or directory`

Comment: sounds like /Volumes/HDD2/ doesn't exist. Try `mkdir /Volumes/HDD2`

Comment: I've checked it. All my directories and folders are already existing.

Comment: check permissions....

Comment: I've checked permission. They are owned by me, no problem with that because I created the folders and I am the owner of the folders. I am on my laptop, not on a network computer.

Comment: What's the output of `df /Volumes/HDD2`?

Answer (score 2):

> `cat sample_pathname.txt`
>
> `"/Volumes/HDD1/001.jpg" "/Volumes/HDD1/002.jpg"`

The quotation marks here are the problem.  Unless you need to cope with file names with newlines in them, the simple and standard way to do this is to list one file name per line, with no quotes or other metainformation.

```
vbvntv$ cat sample_pathname_fixed.txt
/Volumes/HDD1/001.jpg
/Volumes/HDD1/002.jpg

vbvntv$ while read -r file; do
>    mv "$file" "/Volumes/HDD2/"
> done <sample_pathname_fixed.txt
```

In fact, you could even

```
xargs mv -t /Volumes/HDD2 <sample_pathname_fixed.txt
```

(somewhat depending on how braindead your `xargs` is).

Comment: Thanks, tripleee!
I am doing an experiment on a for-loop and Bash array so I did not choose to use a while-loop at first place.

Is it safe to use pathnames without quotes? According to this thread, I want to avoid directory names with apostrophes.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616577/surround-all-lines-in-a-text-file-with-quotes-something

Comment: That's not really how you do it, in general. Once a variable contains the string you want, just make sure you use double quotes around it, like `echo "$file"`.

Comment: So, is it a safe practice to do the following? `while read -r file; do; foo=${echo "${file}" | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g;s/\(.*\)/'\1'/"}; mv "$foo" "/Volumes/HDD2/"; done <sample_pathname_fixed.txt`

Comment: That's not syntactically valid. Are you trying to remove any single quotes while renaming? In Bash you can say `${file/\'//}` to obtain the value with single quotes removed. But if you are trying to escape the single quotes for "safety", just don't.

Comment: What I wanted to accomplish is to ensure that under the while-loop, the directory pathname will always have strong single quotes wrapped around. For instance, it is safe to move a single file by using `mv '/Volumes/HDD1/001's.jpg' '/Volumes/HDD2/bar's directory/'` Under the while-loop, shouldn't I add quotes for the pathname of each line from sample_pathname_fixed.txt?

Comment: Nope. Just don't. The variable should contain just the file name, nothing else. Quote wrapping is only required if you somehow need to `eval` your file names, but nothing like that is happening here.

Comment: ... or you are confusing us thoroughly, and the current direcory has a subdirectory named `'` which in turn contains `Volumes` with `HDD1/001's.jpg'` and `HDD2/bar's directory` containing `'` which is technically quite doable but incredibly inconvenient and highly unlikely. Sounds more like you are hard at work recreating the problem we just solved.

Comment: The example was simply to illustrate the point that we need to use quotes around directory names containing apostrophes or spaces when mv files, but not so when mv files under the while-loop. Nothing more. I am testing pathnames without quotes under a for-loop now.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax used in your example will not create an array... It is just storing the file contents in a variable named array.

> IFS=$'\n' array=$(cat sample_path2.txt)

If you have a text file containing filenames (each on separate line would be simplest), you can load it into an array and iterate over it as follows. Note the use of $(< file ) as a better alternative to cat and the parenthesis to initialize the contents into an array. Each line of the file corresponds to an index.

```
array=($(< file_list.txt ))

for file in "${array[@]}"; do
    mv "$file" "/absolute/path"
done
```

Update: Your IFS was probably not set correctly if the command at the top of the post didn't work. I updated it to reflect that. Also, there are a couple of other reliable ways to initialize an array from a file. But like you mentioned, if you are just piping the file directly into a while loop, you may not need it.

This is a shell builtin in Bash 4+ and a synonym of mapfile. This works great if its available.

```
readarray -t array < file
```

The 'read' command can also initialize an array for you:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array < file
```

Comment: I could call it buffer instead of array too. I try to make it work like an array, and hence the name---maybe a bad idea as I am doing more tests now to see if there is a better approach. Nevertheless, I get the same output if I use `for file in "${array[0]}"; do` In that sense, it is used like an array.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
for file in "/Volumes/HDD1/001.jpg" "/Volumes/HDD1/002.jpg"
do
    f=$(basename $file)
    mv "$file" "/Volumes/HDD2/$f"
done
```

Comment: I tried your code and that led me to conclude that in my long list of files, some files are missing file extensions! That matters! I will report back any issue as I am doing more tests now. Thank you!

Comment: @BartSimpson - if your file extensions are static, then you can simply say `mv "${f%.jpg}.jpg" "/Volumes/HDD2/${f%.jpg}`.jpg". The `%.jpg` will remove `.jpg` extension in the variable name and `.jpg` after the variable name will re-add it. This will ensure that files ending and not ending in `.jpg` will be taken cared of.